Event Grid data connection: "Can not create the data connection without the missing resources"
I'm trying to use the Azure portal wizard to create an Event Grid (Blob storage) data connection, but despite filling out the form with all relevant information, I get an error message upon submitting:
"Can not create the data connection without the missing resources. Here is ARM template for creation." The ARM template provided does not actually work either, as when I try to deploy a custom template using it, I can an error that the ARM template is invalid because of segment lengths something or other.
It seems to me like this Wizard is just straight up broken, but maybe I'm missing something?
Provided below are some addition details and screenshots and illustrate the reproduction of this issue.
Prereqs: An existing Azure Storage Account and an existing Azure Data Explorer Cluster (already provisioned)

Navigate to the storage account, in the left menu, select "Events"

On the screen that says "Events, automated", choose "Azure Data Explorer", then click "Create"

A pane opens on the right side. Select existing ADX cluster

Choose database within ADX cluster, then "Select"

Enter a name for the data connection

Event Type = Blob Created

Choose a Target Table from the ADX Cluster

Choose a target format (in my case JSON)

Choose a mapping (in my case, one I previously created)

Click "Create"


The provisioning will fail with the message I indicated at the start of this question (See screenshot).
Now, I realize that resources are missing (as per error message), but isn't that kind of the whole point of the Wizard? Isn't the Wizard supposed to be smart enough to create any dependent resources? Doesn't it work in topological order?
So either this Wizard is broken, or I'm missing something. Would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me.


Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


Event Grid data connection: "Can not create the data connection without the missing resources".

Initially, I also got the same error when I try to create connection with ADX cluster.

The above error occurs when Microsoft.EventGrid and Microsoft.EventHub Resource Provider is not registered for the subscription.
To resolve the error, you need to register the resource provider in your subscription.

After registering the resource, Event Grid (Blob storage) data connection is successfully created.
Portal:

Reference:
Create an Event Grid data connection - Azure Data Explorer | Microsoft Learn
